# Personalize legend in jchart2d

Tags: java, legend, jfreechart, jchart2d

I want to personalize the legend in a graph created in [JChart2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/).

[image: Example]

At the moment I can get a legend like the one in the left graph in the image, I want something like the legend in the right graph. Is this possible with `JChart2D` or I have to use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at JChart2D source code (version 3.2.2) and it seems that it's impossible to generate the legends you're trying to get (both the left and the right ones): this because in JChart2D a legend is a simple string drawn via `g.drawString(str,x,y);`; hence, there can't be any possible rectangle containing the legend nor images near the strings to improve legend readability.

If you're in a hurry, you might try to change the source code itself by adding a line stroke just before the strings itself. You can do it in `Chart2D.paintTraceLabels(Graphics)` method, near the end of the method itself, via the method `g2d.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);`: you can get the stroke via `trace.getStroke()`.

Alternatively, you can contact the main developer to safely perform the needed change. Hope it helps